# Getting current page position in IE8 when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, scroll, scrollbar

Reference is this page:
http://demo.mypreviewbetasite.com/laverona/menu.html

File in question: http://demo.mypreviewbetasite.com/laverona/scripts/menu.js

The page works as expected in Firefox and Chrome, where as the user scrolls, the position of the window is checked against the position of my sub-menu, so that before it gets scrolled out of view, its position is set to fixed.

However, in IE8, the window position never gets updated as the user scrolls. My testing has shown that IE gets through all the functions, but only updates the windowPos variable when the page loads.

What can be done so that this page behaves the same in IE as it does in FF and Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is from jquery documentation:
  "The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element RELATIVE TO THE DOCUMENT." 
I can't understand why FF or Chrome return $('html').offset().top relative to the client screen/ It seems that IE's approach is more predictable.

Try that (use .scrollTop property of the DOM element instead of .offset().top):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    //alert("subPos: " + subPos);

    //first find the position of the things to sticky
    submenu = $("#sub");
    //submenu.removeClass("no-js");
    subPos = $("#sub").position();
    subPos = subPos.top;

    var preScrollHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('html').item(0).scrollTop;
    var preScrollBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0).scrollTop;

    var checkPos = function(){
    var scrolledHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('html').item(0).scrollTop;
    var scrolledBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0).scrollTop;
    if (preScrollHtml !== scrolledHtml) {
    windowPos = scrolledHtml;
    }
    else {
    windowPos = scrolledBody;
        }
    preScrollHtml = scrolledHtml;
        preScrollBody = scrolledBody;
    calculate();
    }

    var calculate = function() {
    subPos = 64;
    if (windowPos >= subPos){
    $("#sub").addClass("fixed");
    $("#minestre").css("marginTop", "50px");
    }
    else if (windowPos < subPos){
    $("#sub").removeClass("fixed");
    $("#minestre").css("marginTop", "0px");
    }
    //Setting text fields to show the values of everything can help in debugging
    $("#windowpos").val(windowPos);
    $("#subp").val(subPos);
    }




//every time the window scrolls, this function is run
    if ($(window).scroll){
        $(window).scroll(checkPos);
    }
    else if(window.onscroll){
        window.onscroll = checkPos;
    }

});
```

Comment: So that **does** work for IE and FF, But not for chrome. I used an if/else to get chrome to use what I had been doing before, but it calculates the window position differently, so that's a whole new can of worms.

Thanks though, that helps :)

Comment: The only workaround for this I see by now is to check in scroll event handler whether .scrollTop property of 'body' or 'html' had changed and assign to windowPos a respective value. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for new people coming to this question, you may want to check out Andy's answer to a similar question (which also seems to solve this one): https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396681/1793128